# What is the purpose of this operator "+=" in this context?

Tags: javascript, html, operators

I am learning some basic JS and how its results are viewed on HTML. I come across this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Demo: JavaScript Arithmatic Operators</h1>
    <p>x = 5, y = 10, z;</p>
    <p id="p1">x+y=</p>
    <script>
        var x = 5, y = 10;
        var z = x + y
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += z; 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As far as I have read on the operator '+=', it adds the right operand to the left operand and then saves it back to the left operand. However, I am confused on what is the purpose of '+=' in this line?

Comment: try o/p code one time with += and one time with just = you will get the difference.

Comment: with = it only displays the answer.  I presume the string (x+y=)  identified as p1 is concatenated with z (which is 15). Then it saves back to p1 as "x+y=15".

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += z; 

// equals to
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML + z; 

// in this case
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "x+y=" + 15

// finally, you will see "x+y=15" on the page
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have two variable do you want to add these two and store in one of them like

a=5;
b=4;

a = a + b
this is same as a += b;
so in your case you can use

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML + z; 

or 
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += z;
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply appends right operand value(15) to content of <p id="p1"> tag(thats x+y).
So it results as "x+y=15"

For more clarification:

document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += z;
In this line,
it takes the innerHTML(current content) of html element with id 'p1'(here its a <p> tag),
append right operand(here its variable z: which contains value 15 after js add operation result) to that content, and set it back as that <p> tag's innerHTML.